# How to remove a JLabel when I click a certain key on the keyboard?

Tags: java

So I have a GUI, a Tile class and a method class. I created four tiles in my Game class which consists of Tiles that has contains a letter and a color in each of them. I now want to create a method where when I click a key on my keyboard to that specific letter on the tile, it will remove the Tile . How would I go about that? Do I create that method in my model class and call it in my Game(GUI) class?

---

Comment: First, start by using the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API instead of `KeyListener`.  Second, what relationship to the model does the the `JLabel` have and how do you maintain it?  Third, how would the model notify the view that it's changed?  Maybe have a look at [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Comment: This: `private static ArrayList<Tile> list = new ArrayList<Tile>();` is a bad idea, don't make use of `static` in this context, it will cause you no end of issues

Comment: My GUI is supposed to be the observer of my model class. I have no clue on anything about observers. im new to this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your game is the "controller", it's responsible for managing the functionality and communication between the model and view.
- Your view should be a representation of your model
- Your model (and possibly your view) should be providing event notification support, to which you controller will need to monitor, in order to manage the requirements and logic.

To start with, you code is in mess.  You are making to much use of `static` and it's not going to help you.

For example, I re-worked your `Tile` class to look more like this.

```
public class Tile extends JLabel {

    public static Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 39);

    private char _c;

    public Tile(char c, Color background) {
        setBackground(background);
        setOpaque(true);
        _c = c;
        setText(convert());

    }

    public static char randomLetter() {
        Random r = new Random();
        char randomChar = (char) (97 + r.nextInt(25));
        return randomChar;
    }

    public char getChar() {
        return _c;
    }

    public String convert() {
        return String.valueOf(getChar());
    }
}
```

Rather then calling `randomLetter` each time you called `getChar` or `convert`, you should only be using it when you actually need a new character, otherwise you'll never know what the `Tile`'s character actually is/was to begin with

Next, we need some kind of observer contract for the mode, so it can tell us when things have changed, for example.

```
public interface ModelListener {
    public void tileWasRemoved(Tile tile);
}
```

It's nothing special, but this provides a means for the `Model` to provide notification when a `Tile` is removed and which `Tile` was actually removed.

Next, I updated the `Model` so that it actual "models" something.  The `Model` now maintains a `list` of `Tile`s and provides functionality for adding and removing them.  It also provides support for the `ModelListener` and event triggering

```
public class Model {

    private ArrayList<Tile> list = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    private List<ModelListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);

    public Model() {
    }

    public void addModelListener(ModelListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeModelListener(ModelListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected void fireTileRemoved(Tile tile) {
        for (ModelListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.tileWasRemoved(tile);
        }
    }

    public void removeByChar(char value) {
        Iterator<Tile> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Tile tile = iterator.next();
            if (value == tile.getChar()) {
                fireTileRemoved(tile);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private void add(Tile tile) {
        list.add(tile);
    }

    private Iterable<Tile> getTiles() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }
}
```

Next, I went to the `Game` and updated it so it adds `Tile`s to the `Model` and uses the `Model` data to setup the UI.  It then registers the `KeyListener` and `ModelListener`

```
public Game() {
    model = new Model();
    model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.WHITE));
    model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.RED));
    model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.GREEN));
    model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.YELLOW));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    frame.setSize(500, 800);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    for (Tile tile : model.getTiles()) {
        frame.add(tile);
    }

    model.addModelListener(new ModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void tileWasRemoved(Tile tile) {
            frame.remove(tile);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().addKeyListener(this);
    frame.getContentPane().setFocusable(true);
    frame.getContentPane().requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

And finally, the `keyTyped` event now asks the `Model` to remove a `Tile` of the given key...

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    model.removeByChar(e.getKeyChar());
}
```

As a proof of concept...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Game implements KeyListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                new Game();
            }
        });
    }

    private Model model;

    public Game() {
        model = new Model();
        model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.WHITE));
        model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.RED));
        model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.GREEN));
        model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.YELLOW));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        frame.setSize(500, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (Tile tile : model.getTiles()) {
            frame.add(tile);
        }

        model.addModelListener(new ModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tileWasRemoved(Tile tile) {
                frame.remove(tile);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().addKeyListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().setFocusable(true);
        frame.getContentPane().requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        model.removeByChar(e.getKeyChar());
    }

    public interface ModelListener {

        public void tileWasRemoved(Tile tile);
    }

    public class Model {

        private ArrayList<Tile> list = new ArrayList<Tile>();
        private List<ModelListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);

        public Model() {
        }

        public void addModelListener(ModelListener listener) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }

        public void removeModelListener(ModelListener listener) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }

        protected void fireTileRemoved(Tile tile) {
            for (ModelListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.tileWasRemoved(tile);
            }
        }

        public void removeByChar(char value) {
            Iterator<Tile> iterator = list.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Tile tile = iterator.next();
                if (value == tile.getChar()) {
                    fireTileRemoved(tile);
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        private void add(Tile tile) {
            list.add(tile);
        }

        private Iterable<Tile> getTiles() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        }
    }

    public static class Tile extends JLabel {

        public static Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 39);

        private char _c;

        public Tile(char c, Color background) {
            setBackground(background);
            setOpaque(true);
            _c = c;
            setText(convert());

        }

        public static char randomLetter() {
            Random r = new Random();
            char randomChar = (char) (97 + r.nextInt(25));
            return randomChar;
        }

        public char getChar() {
            return _c;
        }

        public String convert() {
            return String.valueOf(getChar());
        }
    }

}
```

## How ever...

As a general rule of thumb, `KeyListener` is a pain to work with and you should be making use of the key bindings API instead, for example

```
import java.awt.AWTKeyStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                new Game();
            }
        });
    }

    private Model model;

    public Game() {
        model = new Model();
        model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.WHITE));
        model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.RED));
        model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.GREEN));
        model.add(new Tile(Tile.randomLetter(), Color.YELLOW));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        frame.setSize(500, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (Tile tile : model.getTiles()) {
            frame.add(tile);
            KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(tile.getChar());
            String name = "typed." + tile.getChar();
            Action action = new TileAction(model, tile.getChar());

            registerKeyBinding((JComponent)frame.getContentPane(), name, ks, action);
        }

        model.addModelListener(new ModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tileWasRemoved(Tile tile) {
                frame.remove(tile);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void registerKeyBinding(JComponent parent, String name, KeyStroke ks, Action action) {
        InputMap im = parent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = parent.getActionMap();

        im.put(ks, name);
        am.put(name, action);
    }

    public class TileAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Model model;
        private char value;

        public TileAction(Model model, char value) {
            this.model = model;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.removeByChar(value);
        }

    }

    public interface ModelListener {

        public void tileWasRemoved(Tile tile);
    }

    public class Model {

        private ArrayList<Tile> list = new ArrayList<Tile>();
        private List<ModelListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);

        public Model() {
        }

        public void addModelListener(ModelListener listener) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }

        public void removeModelListener(ModelListener listener) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }

        protected void fireTileRemoved(Tile tile) {
            for (ModelListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.tileWasRemoved(tile);
            }
        }

        public void removeByChar(char value) {
            Iterator<Tile> iterator = list.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Tile tile = iterator.next();
                if (value == tile.getChar()) {
                    fireTileRemoved(tile);
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        private void add(Tile tile) {
            list.add(tile);
        }

        private Iterable<Tile> getTiles() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        }
    }

    public static class Tile extends JLabel {

        public static Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 39);

        private char _c;

        public Tile(char c, Color background) {
            setBackground(background);
            setOpaque(true);
            _c = c;
            setText(convert());

        }

        public static char randomLetter() {
            Random r = new Random();
            char randomChar = (char) (97 + r.nextInt(25));
            return randomChar;
        }

        public char getChar() {
            return _c;
        }

        public String convert() {
            return String.valueOf(getChar());
        }
    }

}
```

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

Comment: Okay wow.... Was the last part of the code you mashed everything into one? and your using the API instead? i understand your code to a certain point and then everything is just confusion lol . Thanks very much i have to study this now @_@

Comment: There are two runnable examples (they are self contained and can be copied into a single Java class and run).  The first uses `KeyListener`, the second uses Key Bindings

Comment: The observer pattern which I've demonstrated is very similar to Swing's listener model, so if you can understand how that works, then you will understand how Swing's listener API works

Comment: Yea i understand the tile class and the game class you updated, however i dont understand the model class. Im also confused if you created a modellistener interface? I tried your code and theres certain errors on the `add` method in the game class that says "the method add(Tile) from the type Model is not visible" and theres also an error on the `getTiles` method

Comment: First, the code works fine for me, I ran it to test it :P (but I was using Java 8).  The `ModelListener` is created and registered here `model.addModelListener(new ModelListener() {`, just below the `for-loop` to add the tiles to the frame. What about the `Model` class are you confused about?

Comment: I dont understand ModelListeners in general. I tried putting your code in Eclipse and run it, it doesnt run. So you have 3 classes, a Tile, Game, and Model. and a ModelListener interface? so I have 4 of those opened. I run Game and nothing pops up. I am also confused about iterators when you made your method `removeByChar` method

Comment: This is a "long" discussion.  The `ModelListener` is an `interface`, it describes a simple contract. In our case, it describes what the `Model` will do/call when something happens (you only have a single method at the moment). What you do in that method is beyond the caring of the `Model`. This simply provides a callback mechanism which allows the `Model` to tell instances of the `ModelListener` that something has happened.

Comment: Past the code EXACTLY as it's presented in either of the two runnable examples, you will need to understand it before you try carving it up.  Make sure Eclipse is set to run this `Game` class by default.

Comment: The [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) might explain `Iterator`s better.  It's just a nice convenience, you could pass back `List<Tile>` instead

Comment: The biggest issue you seem to be having is understand how object references work and how you can use them.  When ever you create an object, you get a reference to that object in memory, typically you use variables to gain access to them.  You can pass this reference to other methods/class and store those references in arrays and `List`s (as a basic example). The example above simply makes use of this concept by passing a reference of `ModelListener` to the `Model`, which gets stored in a `List`. When the `Model` needs to, it iterates over this list and calls the appropriate method

Comment: Ok thanks very much for your help. Im very slow at understanding the concepts of java right now. But i really appreciate your help. I willt try to understand the concept in what you did. Im also gona try breaking your code into separate classes in my package

Comment: How would you make the tiles drop down ? Right now when you click a char, you remove the upper tile and everything drops up? and also close the frame when you click the last tile

Comment: Insert a JPanel or blank JLabel at position 0, Container#add(Component, int)

Comment: Do I add that into my array list? how would I do that?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, it's not really an aspect of the model, its an aspect of the model

Comment: How do I add the empty tile then?